# session being remembered by browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, session, struts2

I am developing a struts2 web application. When button click occurs, I would make a $getJSON call to a struts action and perform some operation on the java class.

```
$.getJSON('uponClickingBtn',function(data){
        if(data.status=="TRUE"){
            $('#test').attr('src','image/greenzx.png');
        }
        else{
            $('#test').attr('src','image/redzx.png');
        }       
    });
```

The java class would return a String, either "`TRUE`"/"`FALSE`". If the returned value is true, greenzx.png image would appear or else `redzx.png` image would appear.

This process works fine for the first time. But when the same button is clicked again, call to the Java action class does not occur and the browser just returns the latest image.

Say, if it is `greenz.png`, it would again be `greenz.png` instantly.

My browser behaves as if it remembers the value over session which is undesirable. Is this anything to do with the browser setting or I will have to change my code?

PS: I have a requirement to use `IE7`/`IE8` as the browser. It works well with `Firefox`. `IE` is the one where I experience this problem.

Comment: what about other browsers chrome and firefox? working fine in these and ie9+?

Comment: @Jai Works well with firefox as I have already mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the browser caches the response from your action.

- Option 1 - In your JAVA action you have to set HTTP caching to `no-cache`.
- Option 2 - When you use `$getJSON` add a random argument to the url like `'&time=' + Math.random()` (the value has to be unique every time).

The second option can be automatically achieved by using `$.ajax` with the `cache:false` option.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the browser returned the cached data instead of loading the new one. To avoid this, you may add some params to the data url
I.e: add '?time='+new Date().getTime() to the end of the data url.